# ngx-bootstrap accordion isOpen and isOpenChange causing hang

Tags: angular, ngx-bootstrap

I am probably doing something stupid here.
I have an accordion with multiple groups. When one is open the others should close and when an action has been performed on one, then the next one opens. You can obviously go back (like a stepper).

The basic format is this:

```
<accordion closeOthers="1">
    <accordion-group (isOpenChange)="state.categoriesOpen = !state.categoriesOpen"
        [isDisabled]="!categories?.length"
        [isOpen]="state.categoriesOpen">
        <div class="btn btn-link"
            accordion-heading>
            <span>1.
                <span *ngIf="!chosenCategory || !criteria"> Choose category</span>
                <span *ngIf="chosenCategory && criteria"> Category | <b>{{chosenCategory?.name}}</b></span>
            </span>
            <mat-icon>{{ state.categoriesOpen ? 'expand_less' : 'expand_more' }}</mat-icon>
        </div>

        <!-- some content here -->
    </accordion-group>
</accordion>
```

In my code I have this state object defined:

```
state: any = {
    categoriesOpen: true,
    criteriaOpen: false,
    attributesOpen: false,
    formulasOpen: false,
};
```

By default the first group is open. But for some reason it just hangs here forever.
When I remove the **[isOpen]** it works.

Does anyone know why this is broken?

Comment: Is the state object unique per accordion group? Or is the state global? 
You should probably have a separate isOpen state for each group

Comment: The object is for the entire accordion

Comment: It looks like I can't use isOpenChant and isOpen on the same variable

Comment: What do you mean by isOpenChant? This does not exist in your code

Comment: isOpenChange, it was a typo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got this to work removing the **isOpen** and **isOpenChange** attribute. Instead I just used the view child.

```
<accordion closeOthers="1">
    <accordion-group #categoryGroup
        [isDisabled]="!categories?.length">
        <div class="btn btn-link"
            accordion-heading>
            <span>1.
                <span *ngIf="!chosenCategory || !criteria"> Choose category</span>
                <span *ngIf="chosenCategory && criteria"> Category | <b>{{chosenCategory?.name}}</b></span>
            </span>
            <mat-icon>{{ categoryGroup.isOpen ? 'expand_less' : 'expand_more' }}</mat-icon>
        </div>

        <!-- body -->
    </accordion-group>
<accordion>
```

Then in the code I just did this:

```
@ViewChild('categoryGroup', { static: false }) categoryGroup: AccordionPanelComponent;
@ViewChild('criteriaGroup', { static: false }) criteriaGroup: AccordionPanelComponent;
@ViewChild('attributeGroup', { static: false }) attributeGroup: AccordionPanelComponent;
@ViewChild('formulaGroup', { static: false }) formulaGroup: AccordionPanelComponent;

ngOnInit() {
    this.categoriesSubs = this.selectorService.categories.subscribe(categories => {
        if (!categories) return;
        this.categories = categories;
        this.categoryGroup.isOpen = true;
    });
}
```

And when I wanted to open any other group, I could just call it's viewChild like this:

```
this.criteriaGroup.isOpen = true;
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if I exactly understood what you want, but let's see the example:

```
<div class="content">
<accordion closeOthers="1">
<accordion-group #p1 (isOpenChange)="isP1Open = !isP1Open"
    [isDisabled]="!categories?.length"
    [isOpen]="isP1Open">
    <div class="btn btn-link"
        accordion-heading>
        <span>1.
            <span *ngIf="!chosenCategory || !criteria"> Choose category</span>
            <span *ngIf="chosenCategory && criteria"> Category | <b>{{chosenCategory?.name}}</b></span>
        </span>
    </div>
    <button (click)="open(2)">Open panel 2</button>
</accordion-group>
<accordion-group #p2 (isOpenChange)="isP2Open = !isP2Open"
    [isDisabled]="!categories?.length"
    [isOpen]="isP2Open">
    <div class="btn btn-link"
        accordion-heading>
        <span>2.
            <span *ngIf="!chosenCategory || !criteria"> Choose category</span>
            <span *ngIf="chosenCategory && criteria"> Category | <b>{{chosenCategory?.name}}</b></span>
        </span>
    </div>
    <button (click)="open(1)">Open panel 1</button>
</accordion-group>
```

and the corresponding code

```js
import { ViewChild, Component } from '@angular/core';
import { AccordionPanelComponent } from 'ngx-bootstrap/accordion';

 @Component({
   selector: 'my-app',
   templateUrl: './app.component.html',
   styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ]
  })
  export class AppComponent  {
    @ViewChild('p1') p1: AccordionPanelComponent;
    @ViewChild('p2') p2: AccordionPanelComponent;
    public isP1Open: boolean = false;
    public isP2Open: boolean = true;

    public state: any = {
      categoriesOpen: true,
      criteriaOpen: false,
      attributesOpen: false,
      formulasOpen: false,
    };
    public categories: any = [ {name: "test2"}];

    public chosenCategory:any = {name: "test2"}

    public criteria:any = "whatever";

    open(panelNum) {
      const panel = this[`p${panelNum}`];
      panel.isOpen = !panel.isOpen;
    }
}
```

With this you can step through the accordion groups. 
I hope this helps you achieving your goal.
See the example here: https://stackblitz.com/edit/ngx-bootstrap-accordion-panels-lkubjq

Comment: Why do you need the ViewChild, you don't seem to be using it anywhere?

Comment: I can't get this to work. If I update your isOpenChange to a method in the stackblitz, it doesn't seem to ever fire

Comment: How did you update it? Can you show me your Stackblitz code?